# Rails Polymorphic Association, causing 'nil is not a symbol' TypeError from form_for when trying to create new

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations, view-helpers

User Model

```
belongs_to :role, :polymorphic => true
```

admin_profile model (NOT ACTUAL NAME, BUT YOU GET THE IDEA)

```
has_one :user, :as => :role
```

user_profile model (NOT ACTUAL NAME, BUT YOU GET THE IDEA. There are others beyond these two.)

```
has_one :user, :as => :role
```

When I visit /admin_profile/new, I get 'nil is not a symbol' TypeError on line #1.

```
<%= form_for(@admin_profile) do |f| %>
    ...
```

The contents of @admin_profile are:

```
<AdminProfile id: nil, birth_date: nil, url: nil>
```

The trace goes like this

```
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/primary_key.rb:8:in `to_key'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/record_identifier.rb:76:in `record_key_for_dom_id'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_controller/record_identifier.rb:57:in `dom_id'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:388:in `apply_form_for_options!'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_view/helpers/form_helper.rb:365:in `form_for'
```

If there is any other information required, let me know.

Comment: This error is usually caused by a typo. Double-check all your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was some of the tables had :id => false. Let this be a warning to would be users of db:schema:dump

Comment: I caught the same issue. Weird. It doesn't seem to be a persistent problem (just dropping the database and running migrations fixes it fine), but I thought I'd just chime in in case some other kind soul wanted to look into it further. FWIW, I'm on psql.